# Calling a function from factory function in other module doesn't work

Tags: javascript, module, factory

I have two modules: boardObject and displayController... And one factory function: playerFactory... I want to update arrays with a function from playerFactory, but I get error that is not a function.

```
const playerFactory = () => {
    const playTurn = (event) => {
        const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
        boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
        boardObject.render();
        return id;
    };

    return { playTurn   };
};
```

```
const displayController = (() => {
    const playerOne = 'X';
    const playerTwo = 'O'
    const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".game_board");
    let currentPlayer = playerOne;
    
    const switchPlayer = () => {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer === playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
    }
    
    gameBoard.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (event.target.classList.contains("cell")) {
        if (event.target.textContent === "") {
          event.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
          switchPlayer();
          //   const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
          //   boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
          //   boardObject.render();
          currentPlayer.playTurn(event.target);
        }
      }
    });
})();
```

What might be the problem?
This might also help if someone want to look at all the code:

```js
// player factory...
const playerFactory = () => {
  const playTurn = (event) => {
    const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
    boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
    boardObject.render();
  };

  return {
    playTurn
  };
};

// Gameboard object...
const boardObject = (() => {
  let boardArray = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

  const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  // displays the content of the boardArray...
  const render = () => {
    boardArray.forEach((mark, idx) => {
      cells[idx].textContent = boardArray[idx];
    });
  };

  return {
    boardArray,
    render,
    cells
  };
})();

// Display controller ...
const displayController = (() => {
  const playerOne = 'X';
  const playerTwo = 'O'
  const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".game_board");
  let currentPlayer = playerOne;

  const switchPlayer = () => {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
  }

  gameBoard.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("cell")) {
      if (event.target.textContent === "") {
        event.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
        switchPlayer();
        //   const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
        //   boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
        //   boardObject.render();

        ////////
        currentPlayer.playTurn(event); // this is the problem, dunno why?!?!?!?
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #BEE9E8;
}

header {
  background: #1B4965;
  text-align: center;
  color: #62B6CB;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.game_board {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #1B4965;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 5px solid #1B4965;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #62b6cb;
  color: #1b4965;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tic - Tac - Toe<br>The Odin Project</h1>
  </header>


  <div class="game_board">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>




  <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `playerOne` and `playerTwo` are just strings.....  You are never calling `playerFactory`

Comment: TypeError: currentPlayer.playTurn is not a function, but even if I do playerFactory.playTurn it doesn't work...

Comment: Because `currentPlayer` is a string.

Comment: `playerFactory().playTurn()`.  They are both methods.

Comment: Also, the argument to `playTurn` should be `event`, not `event.target`.

Comment: I would highly suggest, you F12 to crack open your developer tools, pop some `debugger;` statements in your code, and step through it.

Comment: `playTurn()` contains a reference to the variable `currentPlayer`. but that's a local variable in `displayController`, so it can't be accessed from another function.

Comment: Now I have the problem that it doesn't change from X to O... like it did before...

Comment: The code on the remote site (which I copied to the stack snippet) is not the same as the code you posted here originally. It has `playerFactory.playTurn()`, not `currentPlayer.playTurn()`. Have you been editing it based on the comments?

Comment: A little bit, but now I have another problem, that it doesn't change current player...

Comment: That's why we don't want you linking to remote sites, it doesn't always reflect the problem you're writing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentPlayer` is just a string `X` or `O`, it doesn't have a `playTurn()` method.

You need to call `playerFactory()` to get the object. In my code below, I use

```
const player = playerFactory();
```

I'm not really sure why you need this object in the first place; it doesn't maintain any state. But maybe that's something you're planning on adding later.

Additionally, `playTurn()` needs to be passed the `currentPlayer` string so it can assign it to the grid element. It's a local variable in `gameController` so it can't access it directly.

```js
// player factory...
const playerFactory = () => {
  const playTurn = (event, currentPlayer) => {
    const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
    boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
    boardObject.render();
  };

  return {
    playTurn
  };
};

// Gameboard object...
const boardObject = (() => {
  let boardArray = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

  const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  // displays the content of the boardArray...
  const render = () => {
    boardArray.forEach((mark, idx) => {
      cells[idx].textContent = boardArray[idx];
    });
  };

  return {
    boardArray,
    render,
    cells
  };
})();

// Display controller ...
const displayController = (() => {
  const player = playerFactory();
  const playerOne = 'X';
  const playerTwo = 'O'
  const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".game_board");
  let currentPlayer = playerOne;

  const switchPlayer = () => {
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === playerOne ? playerTwo : playerOne;
  }

  gameBoard.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("cell")) {
      if (event.target.textContent === "") {
        event.target.textContent = currentPlayer;
        switchPlayer();
        //   const id = boardObject.cells.indexOf(event.target);
        //   boardObject.boardArray[id] = currentPlayer;
        //   boardObject.render();

        ////////
        player.playTurn(event, currentPlayer);
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #BEE9E8;
}

header {
  background: #1B4965;
  text-align: center;
  color: #62B6CB;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.game_board {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 5px solid #1B4965;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 5px solid #1B4965;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #62b6cb;
  color: #1b4965;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tic - Tac - Toe<br>The Odin Project</h1>
  </header>


  <div class="game_board">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>




  <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```